# A music player program/operating system that plays YouTube videos for the Raspberry Pi

Tags: music, youtube, raspberry-pi

I am about to buy the Raspberry Pi to use in a music player setup. Before I buy it, though, I want to figure out what software/operating systems I want to use for my setup.

Requirements:

- Plays from YouTube *playlists* (not just individual videos)
- has a decent web interface (like RuneAudio or Volumio)
- Controllable from remote or keyboard
- Google Cast support would be nice (the real one, not alternatives like BubbleUpNp)

RuneAudio and Volumio seem pretty good, but I can't seem to find anything clear about their YouTube support. Are there any programs/operating systems that meet my requirements?

Comment: AFAIR there is one flavor shipping with Kodi (the media center) right out of the box. I'd wonder if Kodi wouldn't be capable of what you're after. Haven't tried it, though.

Comment: @Izzy I've tried Kodi on other computers. However, YouTube never seems to work, giving me an error. I'll test it, though, once I get my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I've never tried it myself, so no promises – I just read about those special images for the Raspi. Good luck, and let us know then!

Comment: Actually, I just tried the web interface and YouTube and they seem to work fine. Can you post an answer for it?

Comment: Sure, done – see below :) Enjoy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing, I decided to use [Mopidy](https://www.mopidy.com). I just installed Mopidy, the YouTube extension, and a web interface. It works beautifully, but some configuration is required for keyboard/remote control. There's also a distro called [Pi MusicBox](http://www.pimusicbox.com) that comes with this all built-in.

Answer (score 3):

You could use *Kodi* on the Raspi. Their [Wiki gives instructions](http://kodi.wiki/view/raspberry_Pi) for this, and mentions 4 Kodi-centric OS distributions for that:

- [LibreELEC](http://kodi.wiki/view/LibreELEC)
- [OpenELEC](http://kodi.wiki/view/OpenELEC)
- [OSMC](http://kodi.wiki/view/OSMC)
- [XBian](http://kodi.wiki/view/XBian)

They all come with *Kodi* already integrated. The page even has some hints on how to get the best performance out of your little box. Even if you decide for a different distribution, *Kodi* usually can be installed from the repos – though in your case, having it "built in" should be a plus.

To help you on the decision between above 4 "specific distributions", you could take a look at some comparisons/discussions:

- [OSMc vs Openelec VS Librelec](http://forum.kodi.tv/showthread.php?tid=267007) (Kodi forum, English, discussion)
- [Kodi, OpenELEC, OSMC und Raspberry Pi: Die Unterschiede erklärt](https://www.bitblokes.de/2016/01/kodi-openelec-osmc-und-raspberry-pi-die-unterschiede-erklaert/) (German, blog)
- [Unterschiede zwischen "OpenELEC", "LibreELEC" und "OSMC"](https://www.kodinerds.net/index.php/Thread/51724-Unterschiede-zwischen-OpenELEC-LibreELEC-und-OSMC) (German, forum discussion)

In short: *LibreElec* and *OpenElec* are pretty similar (the former is a fork of the latter), and pretty restrictiv concerning "all things open" (so you're less likely to find "closed source" parts there). *OSMC* bases on Debian and is said to be more flexible – same for *Xbian*, which is also described as "small, fast and lightweight". Find the details linked from the Kodi Wiki I mentioned in the first paragraph.

I haven't tried any of them – but you were already able to confirm it should meet your requirements.